# Cassandra is not deleting rows after TTL expires due to Boolean columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Having a table where I am setting the TTL to 7 days, I expect that the Cassandra will delete the rows after 7 days.

My table contains Boolean columns which set the column to True ONLY when creating new rows on the table. The columns are never updated to new value and so these ones are not changing the TTL value with a new TTL value (because Cassandra is column-oriented database).

However, I noticed that after 7 days all the columns are set to NULL values (as expected to get deleted) except from the Boolean columns which remain True and as a result, the rows are never deleted. 
Checked the TTL value of all columns and they have NULL values which means that TTL has expired on ALL columns including the Boolean columns.

When setting the Boolean columns MANUALLY to NULL (after the 7 days) then the rows will be removed immediately as expected.

I can not understand why Cassandra is not setting the Boolean columns to NULL after TTL expires so the rows will be deleting automatically. 
Is the Cassandra working in a different way with Boolean columns and TTL values?

Working with:

- Python 3.6 and
- Cassandra 3.11

Comment: I am assuming from your description, you're determining the cell to be expired by a query showing a value or not. Do you explicitly specify a TTL in the INSERT or do you have the default for the table? I did not experience the same results as you did. I created a table with several columns, one of them a boolean. I set a default_ttl on the table as well as set gc_grace to some low number (doesn't come into play for this discussion). I inserted a row and watched the data from both outside and inside. When ttl elapsed, cql showed null and row showed expired in sstable. Please elaborate your test

Comment: No default_ttl at the table level. I am setting the TTL in the INSERT and also I have set the gc_grace to 1 day.  I am not monitoring the sstables but the rows are getting deleting immediately when changing the bool column to NULL.

Comment: As they should, but I guess I would check the sstables as you might find more of what you're looking for in there (hopefully there are not too many of them). I had a default ttl on the table, inserted the one row, and after the ttl expired, I could see the "expired" = "true" in the sstable as well as no data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: After running `nodetool flush`, the issue fixed and the rows are getting deleted when TTL expires.

That's really weird but it is working and I can see the rows getting deleted immediately. I can not find a reason of not deleting expired rows on the table even though the rows have been marked as expired (*expires= true*) on sstables.